# sed, awk, regex to modify chemical terms

Tags: regex, sed, awk

My platform: Windows 7, 64 bit; 8 GB memory; GNUwin32; `sed` 4.1.5.4013; `awk` 3.1.6.2962.

My problem: long chemical terms.

```
Example_1_: 4-((((2-chloroethyl)nitrosoamino)carbonyl)methylamino)cyclohexanecarboxylic acid.

Example_2_: 3'-O-(3-(N-(4-azido-2-nitrophenyl)amino)propionyl)adenosine-5'-triphosphate.

Example_3_: 2-((2-chloroethyl)methylamino)ethyl-4-ethoxybenzoate.
```

Want to introduce `<wbr>` to give browser opportunity to break a long chemical term.

Want to break after right paren.

However, only want to introduce `<wbr>` if the chemical term has 3 or more right parens.

Further, if chemical term has three or more right parens, only want to introduce `<wbr>` for the last two right parens. Reason: do not want to wrap a term to more than three lines.

```
Example_1_ would look like this: 4-((((2-chloroethyl)nitrosoamino)carbonyl)`<wbr>`methylamino)`<wbr>`cyclohexanecarboxylic acid.

Example_2_ would look like this: 3'-O-(3-(N-(4-azido-2-nitrophenyl)amino)`<wbr>`propionyl)`<wbr>`adenosine-5'-triphosphate

Example_3_ would not be modified because it does not have 3 or more right parens.
```

How to use `sed`, `awk`, `regex` to implement the above?

Thanks in advance for advice.

Comment: tks for format changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for a clear explanation.  This seems to work. I don't have exactly your version of sed.

```
sed 's/)\([^)]*)\)\([^)]*)\)\([^)]*\)$/)\1`<wbr>`\2`<wbr>`\3/' data.txt
```

You did not say which shell you're using.  This is for bash and similar.  For Windows CMD, try double quotes.

Comment: perfect; thank you. And i can build on this if I need to fine tune it.